# How to count total child nodes under the specific parent in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, treeview

Over the last 2 days I have been trying to calculate the child nodes that come under the specific parent in C#. Basically I have in my database an SQL table in that has 2 columns:  user_id, Users_parentId. Example:

```
__________________________
User_Id | Users_parentId
__________________________
100     | Noparent(main)
--------------------------
101     | 100(first User)
--------------------------
102     | 100
--------------------------
103     | 100
--------------------------
104     | 102 (3rd User)
--------------------------
105     | 100
--------------------------
106     | 102
--------------------------
107     | 102
--------------------------
111     | 107 (8th user)
--------------------------
112     | 107
--------------------------
115     | 105 (6th user)
--------------------------
222     | 105 
--------------------------
225     | 112
--------------------------
336     | 112
--------------------------
666     | 112
```

- If we generate a tree from the above table, then it will look like this:

  ```
                       100
              ----------^-------------
              |    |       |        |
            101   102     103      105
           --------^------      ----^--------
           |     |     |         |         |
          104   106   107       115       222
                 ------^-----
                 |          |
                111        112
                      ------^------
                      |     |     |
                    225    336   666
  ```
- So in my project I want to calculate **all child comes under the 100**
- Basically, I tried using get child list and then count their child, and if  they have then again grab the grand_child's child list, and so on, recursively.
- I have tried using for loops and foreach loops, but didn't find a solution.
- I want count total child (means now 100 contains 14 child) at page load event.
- When User logins, at that time I want to calculate all child that come under him.
- I am using Entity framework and LINQ to access the database, My Database name is **GetUnitedDB**, Tablename is **Office_Detail**
- If there are any mistakes or incomplete info provided above, please inform me. And please suggest logic in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a view to your SQL database using the following template:

```
;WITH UserTree AS
        (
            SELECT tn.User_Id UserId, tn.Users_parentId UserParentId, 0 AreaLevel
                FROM Office_Detail tn
                WHERE tn.Users_parentId = 100
            UNION ALL
                SELECT tn.User_Id, tn.Users_parentId, at.AreaLevel+1 AreaLevel
                FROM UserTree at
                    INNER JOIN Office_Detail tn on at.UserId = cn.Users_parentId                    
        )
        select COUNT(UserId)
        from UserTree
```

also consider changing the 100 value to a **parameter** of the type you are using for the user_id and send it in the request of the view.

(this template can also be used to create the tree with its levels)

C# implementation with recursion:

```
private static int Count(int OriginalId)
    {
        using (var ctx = new YourDBContext())
        {
            return FindAllSons(OriginalId, ctx);
        }
    }

    private static int FindAllSons(int id, YourDBContext ctx)
    {
        var res = 1;
        var children = ctx.TableName.Where(x => x.ParentId == id).Select(n => n.Id);
        foreach(var child in children)
        {
            res += FindAllSons(child, ctx);
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: Ok, but i want it in c#... so can you help me within c#

Comment: ok, you used foreach loop, but suppose if any child  doesnt have children , then as per your code foreach loop will terminate, and return count value. Suppose 104 user in tree, foreach loop will not execute for him, becoz no child, and it will breaks loop and will return the number. but what about another users like,106,107...???

Comment: ok.. its work fine.. no mistakes in your code and logic..thank you , u are expert ..

Comment: if a child doesnt have children, he will return 1 and add the value (1) to res.
the total returns after it iterates over all the children